# How to create a local email relay for encrypt mails

Tags: email, email-server, encryption

We have a Ubuntu 20.04 server with redmine installed. Redmine send automated mails through an external smtp provider. We have also other services that do the same thing (teamcity etc)

Everything works fine, but now we need to use gpg for encrypting all mails in my company. With email clients we use enigmail or equivalent plugins, but we have problems with automated mails, like redmine and other services.

We tried some plugin with no results, probably because they're too old, and since we need a solution for every service, we think about installing a smtp relay on one of our servers.

Every service should send mail to this relay, and it encrypt the mail with correct public key and then send it using our smtp provider.

Basically what I'd like to do is

- Configure the relay
- Configure services in order to send mail with this relay
- The relay encrypt mails using correct public keys
- The relay send the email through our external smtp provider

It's possible to create something like that? There's a simple solution or we need to customize something else?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should set up Exim MTA, which can easily be set as a relay server, and to encrypt mails maybe you could check out https://gitlab.com/mikecardwell/gpgit

Comment: Do you want to encrypt the transportation of emails or the emails themselves? Or do you just need to sign them digitally?

Comment: I want to encrypt the mail themselves, like the thunberbird enigmail plugin does.